# Mysql Multiple table select with condition

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements

I have a noob question but rather a troublesome one for me. I am using SELECT on three tables the middle one of which is realtional (Holds relations - ID of user against ID of Place), the first is a table of users, the last of places. I have written this perfectly woking query

```
$query = "SELECT users.Username,usrxplc.User,places.Name
          FROM users,usrxplc,places
          WHERE usrxplc.Place=places.ID AND usrxplc.User=users.ID"
```

That spits out all places associated with all users. Fine, but I would like to limit it only to a certain user. Seems simple, but I am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use a [`WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) clause to filter the results, so just add a clause for `users.ID`:

```
select users.Username,
    usrxplc.User,
    places.name
from users,
    usrxplc,
    places
where usrxplc.Place = places.ID
    and usrxplc.User = users.ID
    and users.ID = 123
```

Comment: You have two `where` clauses instead of `AND`. So it is incorrect. Right one is `...WHERE usrxplc.Place=places.ID AND usrxplc.User=users.ID AND users.UserID = 123`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I have tried it like 1000 times before but kept making stupid mistakes in my syntax.

Comment: +1 as it solve the problem - just felt like offering up the JOIN method :)

Answer (score 2):

Just felt the need to post the alternative - instead of selecting and all tables you can use INNER JOIN to join one table onto another

```
SELECT 
    users.Username,
    places.Name

FROM users
INNER JOIN usrxplc ON usrxplc.User=users.ID
INNER JOIN places ON places.ID = usrxplc.Place

WHERE users.ID = 111
```

It's functionally the same as the other answer, however when you get onto more complex queries and tables you will find that using JOINs allows for greater optimisation as you are able to further limit the rows each individual JOIN gets, for example the following is also valid, where the User row is limited before joining onto other tables

```
SELECT 
    users.Username,
    places.Name

FROM places
INNER JOIN usrxplc ON usrxplc.Place = places.ID
INNER JOIN users ON users.ID = usrxplc.User AND users.ID = 111
```

In more complicated queries, or if these tables were to be far larger, this would in turn offer a more optimal query generally speaking